# Lens space bundles over a circle must come from sphere bundle over a circle?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

The question I would like to answer is the following.

From the classification of sphere bundles we know that the only orientable $S^3$ bundle over $S^1$ is $S^3 \times S^1$.

So suppose we have lens space bundle $L_n(1) \rightarrow P \rightarrow S^1$, where $L_n(1)=S^3/\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the lens space sometimes also denoted by $L(n;1)$, and $P$ is oreintable.

> Does it follow from bundle theory that $P=L_n(1) \times S^1$?

My nose tells me this is true, but I know too little about bundle theory to answer it on my own.

Comment: do you know that the 1st fundamental group of a lens space is finite?

Comment: Yes, the universal cover is $S^3$

Comment: if you could fiber $F\subset L\to S^1$ then the homotopy sequence would gives us a sequence of fundamental groups as $\pi_1(F)\to\pi_1(L)\to\mathbb Z$. Hence $\pi_1(L)$ would be some amalgamated product $\pi_1(F)$ with $\mathbb Z$, which it sounds absurd, don't you think?

Comment: So I've thought about it, and I think that this $\pi_1(L_n(1))\to \pi_1(L_n(1))$ thing is the only obstruction to triviality. And I'm pretty convinced that if $P$ is orientable (which I hadn't taken into account in my previous answer) this obstruction vanishes; but I haven't been able to prove it yet. If I find out how to do that (which amounts essentially to proving that any orientation preserving map $L_n(1)\to L_n(1)$ is homotopic to the identity), then I'll be able to prove that your claim is correct

Comment: @MaximeRamzi by the equivariant Hopf degree theorem, any equivariant selfmap of a sphere with a smooth and free finite group action, is equivariantly homotopic to the identity if and only if it has degree one.